# Hide an android ListView until search string is entered

Tags: android, listview, search-box

I've followed this tutorial http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items and I have the search working on the list.  The only change I'd like to make is to have the list view hidden initially and the results only appearing when the user starts typing.  Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:  Added code.

```
package com.example.testapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ListView lv1;
private EditText ed;
private String lv_arr[]=  {"Android","Cupcake","Donut","Eclairs","AndroidPeople","Froyo",};
private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,   lv_arr));
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if(lv1.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
    lv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
int count) {

textlength=ed.getText().length();
arr_sort.clear();
for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++)
{
if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length())
{
if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,    textlength)))
{
arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
}
}
}

lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>    (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arr_sort));

} 
});
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
   EditText etSearch = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(view.getVisibility() != View.Visible)
                       view.setVisiblity(View.Visible);
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        });
```

Comment: That's still not working for me - can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's working now, however when I tried to bring the code into another project I'm getting a null pointer exception caused by the following line

Comment: lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));

Comment: Sorry was absent, so it's working now? :) nice. Or do you need anymore help?