# android- I can't hide listview berfore typing in editText

Tags: android, listview, search, android-edittext

I have a editText and a listview that works properly. But I want to make the listview invisible until user starts typing. 
I looked into these links but it didn't work

[Show/Hide the Custom ListView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044585/show-hide-the-custom-listview-in-android)

[Hiding Listview until search is initiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748155/hiding-listview-until-search-is-initiated)

[Hide an android ListView until search string is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750330/hide-an-android-listview-until-search-string-is-entered)

Here's my code

```
  public class MapAcWithMarker extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

public ListView listView;
private View parentView;
public DataAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Locations> arrayListTemp=new ArrayList<>();
EditText inputSearch;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_recyc);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            if(listView.getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE)
                listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }



        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
           if(listView.getVisibility() != listView.VISIBLE)
               listView.setVisibility(listView.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide your ListView in onCreate rather than in `beforeTextChanged` and in `onTextChanged` or `afterTextChanged`, you can unhide it.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

instead of

```
 listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First `hide` your `ListView` from lauout `XML` or from `onCreate()` method.

**2.** Show `ListView` from `onTextChanged()` method because this will be called when user type something.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...........
    ..................

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // First hide ListView
    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           // Show ListView
           if(listView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
               listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```